# Dovecot mail location issue

Tags: php, email, imap, vhosts, dovecot

## Issue

Dovecot does not use `mail_location` as I expect.

I want to provide email service for users in LDAP directory.
**User accounts are virtual accounts stored in an LDAP** and they **ARE NOT** mapped to local users.

### Details

#### Package versions

```
OS              Debian GNU/Linux 8.2 (jessie)
dovecot-core    1:2.2.13-12~deb8u1
dovecot-imapd   1:2.2.13-12~deb8u1
dovecot-ldap    1:2.2.13-12~deb8u1
squirrelmail    2:1.4.23~svn20120406-2
postfix         2.11.3-1
apache2         2.4.10-10+deb8u3
```

#### Configuration details

I set in `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf`:

```
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
```

so I expect to mail location be at `/var/mail/vhosts/mydomain.com/myuser` for `myuser@mydomain.com`.

Some dovecot settings, thrown by `dovecot -n` command, are:

```
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
mail_privileged_group = mail
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
protocols = " imap lmtp sieve"
service auth-worker {
  user = vmail
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
}
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf.ext
  driver = ldap
}
```

Looking in `/var/log/mail.log` using `tail -f` command, it throws:

```
Sep 27 19:10:48 balam dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<myuser>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=24907, secured, session=<7/umVr8gvwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Sep 27 19:10:48 balam dovecot: imap(myuser): Error: user myuser: Initialization failed: Namespace '': mkdir(/var/mail/vhosts//myuser) failed: Permission denied (euid=30000(myuser) egid=30002(IT) missing +w perm: /var/mail/vhosts/, dir owned by 5000:5000 mode=0755)
Sep 27 19:10:48 balam dovecot: imap(myuser): Error: Invalid user settings. Refer to server log for more information.
```

which is attempting to create mail directory at `/var/mail/vhosts//myuser`, instead of `/var/mail/vhosts/mydomain.com/myuser` as I want and expect.

If you need more details, please ask me!

#### Tests

In order to test login I have mounted a SquirrelMail client, which trigger previous events logged in `/var/log/mail.log`.

Comment: Maybe [this tutorial will help](http://www.rosehosting.com/blog/mailserver-with-virtual-users-and-domains-using-postfix-and-dovecot-on-a-centos-6-vps/) I used it to build my own multi-domain capable email server with no problems. I think you can find where you it went wrong for you, since the configuration describe in the site is similar to yours

Comment: @samayo, This tutorial is quite different, because config files are different from CentOS 6 to Debian 8 (jessie).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set two parameters - `mail_uid` and `mail_gid` in the config. Until they are not set `deliver` perform database lookup to get adressee's UID and GID. If any - they'll be used for filesystem access. While mail storage hierarcy belong to `5000:5000` LDA have no access to write inside  `/var/mail/vhosts`

Just add an explicit declaration of user who can access mail storage:

```
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
mail_uid = 5000 # or his login name
mail_gid = 5000 # or his group name
```

and restart `dovecot`. Then `deliver` will be invoked with UID/GID=5000. Even more, now you can set mail storage permissions to 700 to prevent anyone except 5000:5000 to access mail storage.

Comment: What about if user info for email accounts are not mapped with local users?
I take email user accounts from LDAP directory.

Comment: Virtual users that haven't corresponding local ones are the general practice nowadays. Not only for mail but for almost every other service that need an authentication. System and services **should** have separate users.

Comment: I have added `mail_uid = vmail` and `mail_gid = vmail` to `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf` file and restarted dovecot (`service dovecot restart`), finally tried to login again but, it still throwing same messages `Initialization failed: Namespace '': mkdir(/var/mail/vhosts//myuser) failed`. I expect some mkdir on `/var/mail/vhosts/mydomain.com/myuser`.